# Removing all seats except driver's + front passenger's one from Volkswagen Sharan 2nd gen. (2010)

Tags: vw, seat

Is it possible to completely remove all seats except driver's + front passenger's one from Volkswagen Sharan 2nd gen. (production started in 2010) to get a very flat loading floor? I was not able to find this information online - it seems to me you can only put the backrests down to achieve flat loading space, but not to remove the seats completely, which still gives you less space that without seats at all.

Comment: Aren't the seats bolted in there in some way? You could remove them this way if you were looking to get them out of the VW, but it is a little more involved than what you are actually asking about, I believe.

Answer (score 3):

I own a SEAT Alhambra, which is quite similar. This is something I looked into before buying the car as I thought I might want to do it.

The 2nd row seats in my car are *apparently* (i.e. I have not actually done it) removable by unscrewing four Torx bolts. However, I believe that the Sharan is slightly different, in that it has 2nd row side airbags. Removal of these is more complex - in particular, you are supposed to use a blocker which connects to the airbag cable and prevents accidental activation while they are in storage (I suspect all this really does is ground a few pins). The workshop manual (ElsaWin) goes into some detail about the procedure for removing the seats.

Note that if you were to remove all the rear seats, you would then have a big loading lip at the back of the car - i.e. it wouldn't be a flat loading bay.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an [online resource](http://www.vybermiauto.cz/autoblok/clanek/test-volkswagen-sharan/ridicova-zona#kabina-a-kufr) in Czech ([translated to English by Google](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=cs&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=cs&ie=UTF-8&u=http://www.vybermiauto.cz/autoblok/clanek/test-volkswagen-sharan/ridicova-zona#kabina-a-kufr)). It says: "Seats are just like the Ford Galaxy and S-MAX can not be removed from the car, but fold into the floor."